# How to give access to users to the home page?

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions

I have a SharePoint site with multiple document libraries.

Permission is broken at the document library level. Various windows groups have been assigned to various document libraries.

User can access the document library via the document library url.

However if they click on home page then they get access denied.

What is the way to give users access to home page?

Why is this disabled by default?

Is there any risk to assigning this permission?

Comment: I think you only shared libraries with users and not "site".

Comment: Correct because I need certain users to view certain document libraries only

Comment: In order to see the home page, you will have to grant "Read" permissions on the "page" (better to give read permissions on site if possible as you have already broken permissions at library level).

Comment: I don't want to give at site level, because they will then automatically have permission to any new document library created hence forth. Is there any risk of giving users access to the home page?

Comment: No issues, you can break permissions at page level and grant access directly on the page. But when you share a site with any new users, you will have to grant access to home page as well for those new users. Let me know if this helps!